scp landsat not showing
why not showing landsat in preprocessing obtion?c
I cannot find Landsat in my preprocessing toolbar.
I have only preprocessing options of clip raster bands, image conversion, masking bands, mosaic band sets, reproject raster bands, split raster bands, stack raster bands, vector to raster.
How can i solve?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
